# Is open = openly?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please help me to understand the phrase "Cracking open a tinned cocktail on the tube may be frowned upon". I'm confused with the word "open". I can understand this phrase without "open" or with "openly" but what the original construction means?

Comment: *Cracking open* is the same as, and colloquial for, *opening*. Neither *open* or *openly* would be grammatical in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"Cracking open a tinned cocktail" means "Opening a tinned cocktail by cracking it".  You could also say "Opening a tinned cocktail".

Cracking something (without "open") usually means breaking it, not opening it.  "openly" means "publicly" and does not make sense here.